# Celery: Use PostgreSQL instead of RabbitMQ

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq, celery

Is it possible to use a different message broker with celery?

For example: I would like to use PostgreSQL instead of RabbitMQ.

AFAIK it is only supported in the result backend: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#database-backend-settings

Since PostgreSQL 9.5 there is `SKIP LOCKED` which enables implementing robust message/work queues. See https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/

Comment: Have you read Celery's documentation on brokers? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#broker-settings

Comment: database transport support code was removed before, but be added back recently: https://github.com/celery/kombu/tree/master/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy

Comment: @RonanBoiteau according to the docs there are several supported transport schemas. amqp://, redis://, sqs://, and qpid://.  This looks like it is not supported to use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, you can use postgres as broker instead of rabbitmq. Here is a simple example to demonstrate it.

```
from celery import Celery 


broker = 'sqla+postgresql://user:pass@host/dbname'

app = Celery(broker=broker)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Queuing tasks

```
In [1]: from demo import add

In [2]: add.delay(1,2)
Out[2]: <AsyncResult: 4853190f-d355-48ae-8aba-6169d38fad39>
```

Worker results:

```
[2017-12-02 08:11:08,483: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: t.add[809060c0-dc7e-4a38-9e4e-9fdb44dd6a31]  
[2017-12-02 08:11:08,496: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task t.add[809060c0-dc7e-4a38-9e4e-9fdb44dd6a31] succeeded in 0.0015781960000822437s: 3
```

Tested on latest(celery==4.1.0, kombu==4.1.0, SQLAlchemy==1.1.1) versions.

Comment: is there an advantage to use postgre, than rabbitMQ?

Comment: @pelos Yes. Less overhead on maintenance/deployment of another component in your stack. However, it is recommended not to use db as broker if you have high workloads. Relevant discussion at https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5149.

Comment: This does not work anymore. in recent Celery versions, you can't use database as a broker.

Comment: @RamyM.Mousa Which version are you using? It seems to be working fine with celery==5.0.0 also.

Comment: at least highly undocumented, if it still works with 5.3?! having to run a rabbit or redis was always a showstopper in smaller projects.

Comment: Still works with Celery 5.2. It should be documented, having a backend AND broker without no extra tool is highly valuable in local environment IMO.

Comment: I actually added the removed support back but it is not documented yet and of course need improvements.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use a different message broker with celery?

before Version 4, it's sure yes! i have ever use mongodb for message broker in Celery 3, following the [official document](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/getting-started/brokers/mongodb.html)。

so if want to use PostgreSQL as the broker，it's ok，Celery also support [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/getting-started/brokers/sqlalchemy.html).

However, if you want to use it in Celery 4.0, maybe it's a little difficult，one way in my mind is change the code for Kombu，yes，it's Kombu，not Celery！