# why celery is creating new queue in rabbit mq?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, psycopg2, psql

[image]

the function that send to celery is using the decorator poinitng to the queue that i want to use such:

```
@app.task(queue="celery")
def compare_from_database(row_id=None, database_name=None, table_name=None):
    ....
```

i created a script to check how many task i still have in the queue, just a while loop of the command

```
 rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

and parsing the line with "celery"

but since celery creates random queues i cant use that.  why celery is creating new queues and not really sending it to the one i want?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using `rpc` as your `celery_result_backend`.
You can check out this link - https://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2015/04/30/making-celery-play-nice-with-rabbitmq-and-bigwig/ where he explains that RPC backend will create queues for the task results.

---

You can check my answer for more explanation about `result-backend` here =>
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62069822/6490744

Comment: very interesting that even with apply_async([args], queue="celery") and still doesnt go to that queue,    then why do we have the decorator with @app.task(queue="celery")?   so passing the queue in the apply_async, or the decorator doesn't really work =(    i will make the function update a postgree with a column call Done, instead,  thanks for the article, was very interesting.

Comment: just remove the `rpc` backend , then it should go to the right `queue`  .

Comment: you can use `postgres` as `result-backend` if you want to store results in `postgres` , its damn simple .

Comment: yes,  super simple, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473583/celery-use-postgresql-instead-of-rabbitmq

Comment: ok . i dint know you could use postgres `instead` of rabbit . what i meant was you can use `celery + rabbit` with  `postgres as result-backend` . result-backend is to store whatever the celery tasks return.

Comment: Sowjanya,  celery can have rabbit, redit, and now with that tutorial i learned that can also use postgres =),   yes  i know what you meant  having rabbit as broker and storing the results in postgres as the database to store the results.

Comment: The link is broken