# Do post response validation of a Bottle.py request

Tags: postgresql, celery, bottle

I have a Bottle.py server that, after it returns a response must do a PostgreSQL database call(s) to validate/update the data.  My thinking was to do a Celery or RQ task queue but I can't find if Celery is supported or an example of integrating the two.

How would you, after sending a response back to the application, run one to three database commands to validate the data?

Thanks
John

Comment: Please do more research on this request before posting. Do your research on brokers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473583/celery-use-postgresql-instead-of-rabbitmq

https://medium.com/@rajesh_khadka/background-tasks-in-flask-sqs-celery-postgresql-2a7bc8558942

https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-and-celery/

Bottle.py is quite similar to Flask.

Try these. If they don't work for you. Post the code that you tried.

For now, I think question is too low effort.

Comment: The comment that Flask and Bottle are similar should get me to the answer.  Thank you

Comment: Have you considered simply kicking off a thread/process/greenlet that will run after you return your response?

Answer (score 1):

Please look into brokers for Celery. Additionally, Flask is quite similar to Bottle.

You can try these:

[Celery with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473583/celery-use-postgresql-instead-of-rabbitmq)

[Tutorial with steps](https://medium.com/@rajesh_khadka/background-tasks-in-flask-sqs-celery-postgresql-2a7bc8558942)

[Flask & Celery](https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-and-celery/)